# Imported variable is not defined

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, import, undefined

I'm writing a simple program that imports functions from another program. It basically converts Fahrenheit to Celsius or vice versa, depending on what kind of input you give it. Here's the code for the main program:

```
temp = int(input('What is the temperature? '))
print('Is this temperature in fahrenheit or celsius?')
system = int(input('Please put 1 for Fahrenheit and 2 for Celsius: '))
if system == 1:
    from tempconvert import celsius
elif system == 2:
    from tempconvert import fahrenheit
else:
    print('I dont understand.')
```

And here's the code for the program the functions being imported are coming from:

```
def fahrenheit():
    fahrenheit = temp * 1.8 + 32
def celsius():
    celcius = temp - 32
    celsius = celcius / 1.8
```

When I go do it, it'll take the temperature I enter, and it'll accept the distinction between Fahrenheit and Celsius. But then it'll say that `temp` in the imported functions is not defined. But I thought that it would be defined by the main program. So any suggestions as to how to fix this is welcome, because I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, names defined in a function will look in the globals of the module *they are defined in*, **not** the module they are imported in.
 
<sub>All function objects have a *hidden* attribute named `__globals__` that keeps a reference to the dictionary holding the names available in the *defining* module.</sub>

You'll need to define your functions with the appropriate argument `temp` and pass that in when invoked.

```
def fahrenheit(temp):
    fahrenheit = temp * 1.8 + 32

def celsius(temp):
    celcius = temp - 32
    celsius = celcius / 1.8
```

this also has the nice side effect that `temp`, as a local name for the functions, is loaded a bit faster :-)

Answer (score 1):

First you will want to make sure that your functions are taking in a parameter, in this case temp. You will also want to have the function return a value your main code block

```
def fahrenheit(temp): 
    fahrenheitTemp = temp * 1.8 + 32
    return fahrenheitTemp

def celsius(temp):
    celciusTemp = temp - 32
    celciusTemp = celciusTemp / 1.8
    return celciusTemp
```

Next you need to modify your main code block. Right now you are importing the function from the other module correctly, but you aren't using it. To use your function use the name you specified after the `def` key word in the other module with `()` at the end, and put all the parameters you specified inside the `()`

Lets try taking in the current temp and passing that to your function and then returning and printing the converted temperature. Here goes:

```
temp = int(input('What is the temperature? '))
print('Is this temperature in fahrenheit or celsius?')
system = int(input('Please put 1 for Fahrenheit and 2 for Celsius: '))

if system == 1:
    from tempconvert import celsius
    print(celsius(temp))      

elif system == 2:
    from tempconvert import fahrenheit
    print(fahrenheit(temp))

else:
    print('If at first you don't succeed... try try again!')
```